# If condition not work regular in bash

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

Code

```
if [ $setup==="y" ]
    then
        echo "kurulum:"$setup
        exit
        full_dir=$full_dir"/public"
    else
    echo "Sub-Public folder is exist? [public,web]"
        read folder_extend
        if [ $folder_extend ]
                then
                full_dir=$full_dir"/"$folder_extend
        fi
fi
```

Setup param $setup view as "n" after run sh but still condition firts part run. Where wrong code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to:

```
if [ "$setup" = "y" ]
    then
        echo "kurulum:"$setup
        exit
        full_dir=$full_dir"/public"
    else
    echo "Sub-Public folder is exist? [public,web]"
        read folder_extend
        if [ "$folder_extend" ]
                then
                full_dir=$full_dir"/"$folder_extend
        fi
fi
```

It should just be a single `=`, and you need spaces around it. You should also quote variables in most contexts, in case they contain spaces.

Comment: @aybarscengaver: How do you populate $setup?

Comment: You don't have spaces around `=` in the `if` test.